# Angular4 API request which respond not only array of products

Tags: angular

I have API endpoint, which respond me with data

```
{
  "success": true,
  "end": true,
  "type_product": "current",
  "product": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "The first product",
      "hideTotalNumberOfSharesOnFrontEnd": true,
      "productSummary": "Product Summary,"
      "company": {
        "registeredOfficeSuburb": null,
        "registeredOfficeState": null,
        "registeredOfficeStreet": null,
        "registeredOfficePostcode": null
      },
      "date": {
        "timestamp": 1520899198,
        "days": 200,
        "hours": 15
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have interface for Product and Company but when I do request, I can't get each property. It's a function inside service:

```
getProductList(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint + '/api/products').map(res => res.json().payload);
}
```

Then inside product component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.productApiService.getProductList().subscribe(data => {
      debugger;
      //have undefined here
   });
}
```

I try to do some manipulation inside getProductList, because it's must return an array if Observable of Product, but still can fixed my issue.

Question is: How I can get product and company info from API request

Comment: I see our json in not valid though

Comment: Are you using new HttpClient for HTTP requests? If so, then you dont need to res.json().payload, just map(res => res)

Comment: @AntonLee I using import {Http} from "@angular/http"; and pass it to constructor

Comment: @Rahul it's only an example of what I received to simplify

Comment: Then I don't see `payload` object in your response. `map(res => res.json())` will return response JSON object.

Comment: @AntonLee still nothing

Comment: This is the whole object, you need to get products, then write map(res => res.json().product)